# How to use the same internet connection over two machines with different MAC addresses?

Tags: windows, internet, ethernet, isp, mac-address

My service provider does some binding to my Ethernet MAC address. So, I am not able to use the connection on a second machine that I need to use (I need to use both the machines, though not at the same time).

**Apart from changing the MAC address on the adapter of the second machine, is there any other way to achieve this?**

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a standard router?

Comment: @bryan: What standard router? Like buying a router hardware?

Comment: Yes (I need 15 characters to reply)

Comment: As all the answers also say...yes, just buy a router!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either get yourself a home router and ensure they bind to it's MAC address (often this is just a matter of unplugging the modem for a while before then plugging it into the new network device, sometimes you have to call the ISP), or get a router that allows spoofing and use that feature to make the router appear to have your currently bound MAC address.

If the computer hooked to the Internet has more than one network adapter you could also turn on [Internet Connection Sharing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234815) in Windows and use that machine as a router to supply Internet to the other computer.

HTH...

Answer (score 1):

Some routers have MAC cloning.  I'm pretty sure my Linksys did.  I'd invest in a cheap router that allows this.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer gets an IP address from your ISP via DHCP, releasing the IP address may unregister the MAC address on your ISP's end. Here's how to try:

Go to a Command Prompt, type `ipconfig /release` and press Enter. When you get the result showing an IP address of 0.0.0.0, unplug the Ethernet cable from your computer.

Plug the Ethernet cable into the second computer. Open a Command Prompt, type `ipconfig /renew` and press Enter. If it works, you'll see a valid IP address appear. If it doesn't work, it will take a minute or so and eventually show a message that the request timed out.

If it does work, you'll have to remember to do the same release process before unplugging the Ethernet cable on each computer.

As others have mentioned, a router is a more convenient solution that will allow you to use multiple computers on the same connection simultaneously. If your ISP does unregister the MAC address when you release the IP address, then you can release it before connecting the router to avoid having to find the router's MAC cloning settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a NAT router and then connect your two PCs to the router. Then you could even use both machines at the *same* time if you wanted to.